# iOS - requesting data for multiple tables from the same database returning incorrect values

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, database, sqlite

I'm currently attempting to make a call to a localized sqlite3 database to load particular values from multiple tables. The first request is made to fetchAllAmmoForDiamter which in turn calls fetchBCForAllAmmoModels. I can verify that my request statement is correct, as when running it in SQLite Database Browser 2.0 as a query statement, it returns the correct values. When running this on the iOS application though, it returns 0 for everything. Would anyone know why this is occurring?

```
 - (NSArray *)fetchAllAmmoForDiameter:(NSNumber *)d
{
    sqlite3 *database;
    NSMutableArray *allAmmoModels = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSString *db = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bulletlib" ofType:@"sqlite3"];

    if (sqlite3_open([db UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        double diameter = [d doubleValue];
        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT _id, manufacturer_id, weight, length, model, hide_bcs FROM bullets WHERE diameter=%f ORDER BY diameter, manufacturer_id ASC", diameter ];
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                int uniqueID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
                int manufactureID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1);
                double weight = sqlite3_column_double(statement, 2);
                double length = sqlite3_column_double(statement, 3);
                char *model = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4);

                //            NSLog(@"%d,%d,%f,%f %f, %s", uniqueID, manufactureID, diameter, weight, length, model );

                NSString *modelName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:model];
                AmmoDatabaseModel *dbModel = [[AmmoDatabaseModel alloc]initWithUniqueId:uniqueID manufactureId:manufactureID diameter:diameter weight:weight length:length andModel:modelName];

                [allAmmoModels addObject:dbModel];
            }

        } else {
            printf( "could not prepare statemnt: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
        [self fetchBCForAllAmmoModels:allAmmoModels];

    }
    return allAmmoModels;

}


-(void)fetchBCForAllAmmoModels:(NSArray *)ammoModels

{
    for (AmmoDatabaseModel *ammoModel in ammoModels ){

        ammoModel.ballisticCoefficients = [self fetchBCForAmmoModel:ammoModel];

    }


}

-(NSArray *)fetchBCForAmmoModel:(AmmoDatabaseModel *)ammoModel
{
    NSMutableArray *bcModels = [NSMutableArray new];
    sqlite3 *database;
    NSString *db = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bulletlib" ofType:@"sqlite3"];

    if (sqlite3_open([db UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {


        NSString *query =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT drag_func, bc, minvel FROM bullet_bcs WHERE bullet_id=%i", [ammoModel.uniqueID intValue]];
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                int dragFunction = sqlite3_column_double(statement, 1);
                double bc = sqlite3_column_double(statement, 2);
                int minvel = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 3);
                BallisticCoefficientDatabaseModel *bcModel = [[BallisticCoefficientDatabaseModel alloc] initWithDragFunction:dragFunction coefficient:bc minimumVelocity:minvel];
                [bcModels addObject:bcModel];
            }

        } else {
            printf( "could not prepare statemnt: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);

    }
    return bcModels;
}
```

Comment: You're not handling the else statement for the sqlite3_prepare_v2 call. Are you sure an error is not occurring there? Can you add the else and try to NSLog the error? If there is an error, by your code logic you'd be returning an empty array, which is what appears to be happening.

Comment: I will keep that in mind and do that. The only reason I didn't test via in the else is because it does in fact enter the loop.

Comment: I updated the code as shown above and ran it. No errors printed out to the console, and now the db is definitely closed before ending or making the next SQL request.

Comment: Well then next I would open the database in my console to confirm that data is actually being stored in the database. You can nslog the db variable you have with your database path, cd into the directory, then run 'sqlite3 bulletlib.db". In the sqlite3 page, run a .dump command. If the data is infact there, then the problem is surely your select query.

Comment: Now you close the database even if it isn't opened.

Comment: Yea, right before the prepare statement in your fetchBCForAmmoModel function, I would nslog the query and then stick a breakpoint right before the prepare statement. Then copy the select statement and run it directly into your database using my comment above.

Comment: I've already done this as stated above.. The query works when directly interfacing with the db on another interface. and yea.. I don't believe there's any harm programmatically closing an unopened db. At least not one that I could find. The actual request when it goes through is in fact correct. I know that much. What I don't know, is if I'm handling iOS's sql interfacing correctly or if there are limits I'm unaware of.

Comment: @JeremyNortey The db is a pre made db. The values are pre defined, not created during the runtime of the application. The values exist as per browsing the db via a SQLite Browser and I'm able to query the variables/table data that I want via the same query statement being used above (which I po'ed from the command prompt during runtime of the application and pasted into another sqlite interfacing application).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was making the right query and was getting my data successfully. The major issue was the schema for the db (for some crazy reason) wasn't pulling the correct data in the noted rows and columns it should have. I printed out my data while stepping using

```
NSString * str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
```

and aligned the results with their respective values.